# Rails + Ajax + Need to refresh page to get the right session value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, session

My problem is that i am in the need to refresh the page to get the right value of a session i modify through ajax calls in the same page. Any idea about this stuff ?

Comment: You're not getting the correct session on the server side? I mean your controller, is it? Little bit of code(where you're facing problem) can actually help people on SO to help you. Just asking about idea on a statement is completely vague.

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript you can refresh your page using `location.reload();`

You can load that code on success of your ajax call.